# Scrolling view during putting text i EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-scrollview

How to make the whole view scrollable during typing in EditText?
I am doing the Registration screen and I get stuck here.

I've got a scrollview and relativelayout inside where are edittext's and buttons.

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_input"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo"
        android:background="@drawable/no_corner_edit_text"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="@string/email_address"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
             android:id="@+id/password_input"
             android:layout_width="260dp"
             android:layout_height="35dp"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_below="@id/login_input"
             android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
             android:background="@drawable/no_corner_edit_text"
             android:inputType="textPassword"
             android:hint="Password"
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button1"
        android:layout_below="@id/password_input"/>  


    <Button
        android:text="Create Account"
        android:id="@+id/create_account_button"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@drawable/grey_button1"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_button"/>



    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ScrollView is not working at all.

Comment: Post some code so we can have a better idea of what you're trying to do. You might want to look at the [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) API for more information on scrolling views.